# How to attach and view pdf documents to access database

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, pdf

I have a very simple database in access, but for each record i need to attach a scanned in document (probably pdf). What is the best way to do this, the database should not just link to a file on the pc, but should copy and keep the file with it, meaning if the original file goes missing the database is moved or copied, the file should still be accessable from within the Database. Is This possible? and what is the easiest way of doing it? If is should i can write a macro, i just dont know where to start.  and also when i display a report of the table, i would like to just see thumbnails of the documents.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answerers have noted, storing file data inside a database table can be a questionable practice. That said, I wouldn't personally rule it out, though if you are going to take that option, I'd strongly suggest splitting out the file data into its own table in its own backend file. For example:

- Create a new database file called `Scanned files.mdb` (or `Scanned files.accdb`).
- Add a single table called `Scans` with fields such as `FileID` (AutoNumber, primary key), `MainTableID` (matches whatever is the primary key of the main table in the main database file), `FileName` (Text), `FileExt` (Text) and `FileData` ('OLE object', really just a BLOB - don't actually use OLE Objects because they will bloat the database horribly).
- Back in the frontend, add a reference to `Scans` as a linked table.
- Use a bit of VBA to upload and extract files from the `Scans` table (if you're interested in the mechanics of this, post a separate question).
- Use the VBA `Shell` routine (if you must) or `ShellExecute` from the Windows API (= the better option IMO) to open extracted data.

If you are using the newer ACCDB format, then you have the 'attachment' field type available as smk081 suggests. This basically does most of the above steps for you, however doing things 'by hand' gives you greater flexibilty - for example, it allows giving each file a 'DateScanned' or 'DateEffective' field.

That said, your requirement for thumbnails will require explicit coding whatever option you take. It *might* be possible to leverage the Windows file previewing API, though I'd be certain thumbnails are a definite requirement before investigating this - Access VBA is powerful enough to encourage attempts at complex solutions, but frequently not clean and modern enough to allow fulfilling them in a particularly maintainable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Attachment type under Data Type when you go into Design View of your table.  You can add an attachment field here.  When you go into the Datasheet view of the table you can select this field for a particular row and a window will open for you to specify the attachment.  This will cause your database to quickly grow in size if you add a lot of large attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OLE field in a table, but I would really suggest you not use this approach.  The database is going to be HUGE in no time, and you're going to regret it.

Instead, you should consider adding a field that stores the path to the file, and keep the files in one folder on your network.  Then you can use a SHELL() command to open the file.  What's the difference between restoring an Access database and restoring PDF files if something goes wrong?  This will keep your database at a manageable size and reduce the possibility of corruption.